# Freeradius server authentication issue

Tags: authentication, networking, freeradius

I'm thinking of using radius in an open network to allow some navigation in a some local pages, and require authentication for Internet access. Is there any way to configure FreeRADIUS in that way? For example, have a NodeJS app and FreeRADUIS running in an ubuntu server, when a user connects to the network, redirect to a page that let's him use the NodeJS app, or sign in for Internet use

Answer (score 1):

No.  You need to use a captive portal server like Coova in order to provide walled garden functionality.

FreeRADIUS just implements the network policies.

Comment: thnku i want to know how i assign vlan taging to my user using fre radius

Answer (score 0):

If you want to redirect users to your application , then you must configure router with firewall rules, and you also have to setup captivate portal on this router (Like nodogsplash, coova-chilli) 
In coova chilli you can define login url path.
freeradius is only for authentication,policy setup ,and data accounting.

In my scenario I am using mikrotik router with capative portal and freeradius setup. I set up router policy from freeradius (radreply section) **WISPr-Redirection-URL** 
for refrence you can check here: [Mikrotik official site for radius attributes](https://wiki.mikrotik.com/wiki/Manual:RADIUS_Client)